# Implementing F# workflow builders: handling exceptions in for..in..do constructs

Tags: f#

In continuing to explore F# workflow builders, I decided to experiment with exception handling in the builder, in particular in the "for..in..do" construct.

The end goal for this experiment is a workflow builder that will continue processing the sequence even when an exception occurs.

The below, for example, doesn't work, because the For method of the builder does not appear to get called until after the point where the exception occurs (at the first Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir) call)

```
type failSafeSeq() =
    member this.For(seq1, mapFunction) =
        try
            seq1 |> Seq.collect mapFunction
        with
            ex -> Console.WriteLine ex
                  Seq.empty
    member this.Yield(yieldExpr) = yieldExpr |> Seq.singleton
    member this.YieldFrom(yieldBang) = yieldBang
    member this.Combine(a, b) = Seq.append a b
    member this.Delay(delayFun) = delayFun()
    member this.Zero() = Seq.empty 

let failSafe = new failSafeSeq();

let rec allFilesSeq dir =
    failSafe { for file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir) do yield file
               for subdir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories dir do yield! (allFilesSeq subdir) }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    allFilesSeq "C:\\System Volume Information\\" //almost guaranteed to cause an UnauthorizedAccessException on Windows systems at the first Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir) call.
    |> Seq.iter Console.WriteLine
    0
```

Is this possible using F# workflows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; as per the [spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597448) on computation expressions,

```
... for pat in expr do cexpr ...
```

is translated to

```
... b.For(expr, fun pat -> cexpr) ...
```

which means `expr` is evaluated before the `For`, and if it throws, then of course `For` is not called.

Incidentally, your strategy also would not work as-is, since `seq`s are lazy, and e.g. `Seq.collect` will not typically throw (rather, the code that calls it and evaluates the sequence may cause code to run that throws).

There are a number of other ways you could implement something along the lines of 'recovering `seq`s'... I think a workflow is perhaps the wrong approach, and instead you just want some wrapping combinators for `seq` creation and mapping.

What is the real end goal?  This 'recovering `seq`' does not seem useful to me, how do you intend to apply it?

Comment: At this point, I'm just trying to explore F# as a language, and get familiar with concepts that aren't familiar to me. In this case, I am just trying to explore the boundaries and functionality of F# workflows.  Incidentally, I decided to try this example as a semi-opposite of the "Maybe" monad/workflow after reading http://leibnizdream.wordpress.com/2008/10/21/why-use-computation-workflows-aka-monads-in-f/.  I'll move to more practical coding later :).  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I'd like to have the same type. A fault-tolerant pipeline. Any progress on a solution?